# Auto_increment trigger

Tags: mysql

I need to auto_increment the primary key in a mysql database using a trigger. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to do this. In the sample code I have provided, I need the employee table primary key to auto_increment beginning with an empty table and a starting value of 200. Then, I need each new insert to increment by 1.Thanks for looking and I hope you are able to help me.

```
CREATE TABLE department (
dept_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL  Primary Key
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
emp_id INT(6) unsigned Default 0 Not NULL 
, last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
, first_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
, dept_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, dept_name)
,  FOREIGN KEY(dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
);
```

Comment: I tried the following, but it is telling me I have a syntax error: `CREATE TRIGGER empid_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `employee`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE m INT;

    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(emp_id), 200) + 1 INTO m FROM professor_tbl;
    SET NEW.value = m;
    -- NOT NEEDED but to be save that no other record can be inserted in the meanwhile
    SET NEW.emp_id = m;   
END;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you need to do:

1. Declare the `emp_id` column as `AUTO_INCREMENT`;
2. Set the value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` property of the table to `200`;
3. **Do not** provide any value for column `emp_id` when you `INSERT` rows in table `employee`.

Change the table creation as below:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    dept_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(emp_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(dept_name) REFERENCES department_tbl(dept_name)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=200;
```

If the table has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column then it must be the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table. I removed `dept_name` from the definition of the `PK` above. I also removed the default value `0` from the `emp_id` column. It's default value is generated by MySQL using the `AUTO_INCREMENT` policy.

When you `INSERT` a new record into the `employee` table all you have to do is to **not** provide any value for the `emp_id` column:

```
INSERT INTO employee (last_name, first_name, dept_name)
VALUES ('Doe', 'John', 'accounting');
```

Then use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) MySQL function to retrieve the value of the `emp_id` generated on insertion.

The language or the library you use to develop the client application probably has a function that wraps `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and returns its value.

Comment: I get a #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint when I try to add your table. I get this whenever I try to use auto_increment in the employee table. If I add auto_increment to the department table There is an error in the last line (my mistake). It should be FOREIGN KEY(dept_name) REFERENCES department(dept_name). Even with this corrected, I get the same error.

Comment: I was able to make adjustments to make this work. I added key index_deptName(dept_name) before the foreign key. That did the trick!